# Setting Oracle size of row fetches higher makes my app slower?

Tags: java, performance, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

As detailed [here](http://webmoli.com/2009/02/01/jdbc-performance-tuning-with-optimal-fetch-size/) and confirmed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10979/basic.htm#g1028323), the default number of rows Oracle returns at time when querying for data over JDBC is 10. I am working on an app that to has to read and compare lots of data from our database. I thought that if we just increase `defaultRowPrefetch` to be something like 1000, then surely our app would perform faster. As it turned out, it **performed slower** and by about 20%.

We then decided to just slowly increase the number from 10 and see how it performs. We've seen about a 10% increase by setting it somewhere between 100 and 200. I would have never guessed, however, that setting it higher would make our app perform more slowly. Any ideas why this might happen?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Just for clarification, I'm using Oracle 11g R2 and Java 6.

**EDIT 2:**

Okay, I wanna restate my question to be clear, because judging from the answers below, I am not expressing myself properly:

> How is it possible that if I set a higher fetch size, my app performs slower? To me, that sounds like saying "We're giving you a faster internet connection, i.e. a fatter pipe, but your web browsing will be slower.

All other things being equal, as they have been in our tests, we're super curious about how our app could perform worse with only this one change.

Comment: How long - as in how much data - is each row being fetched, as a rough estimate?

Comment: We're talking reading a few thousand rows several hundred times each, e.g. 10,000 rows * 500 times

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing that kind of heavy lifting inside the database itself?

Comment: Yeah, because basically we're grabbing data from two different databases and they can't be linked at all. So we need a third party to do the comparison.

Comment: are these 2 databases both Oracle instances?  Or Oracle and some other db.  If so, how do u know the issue is with pulling data from Oracle?

Comment: Yes, both databases are Oracle, and we're fairly sure that's the issue because we run our job twice (which did the same thing in both cases) and with the default fetch size of 10, it took 10 minutes and with a fetch size of 1000 it took 12 minutes.

Comment: Your issue might be because of multiple reasons one being network, second being your JVM memory allocation, I am hoping that your DB is not getting accessed by anything else and thus there is no issue on DB. Is your DB on a different machine on a network? in this case TCP might be playing a big role in data transport. Also why don't you write a program which runs your code multiple times with increasing defaultRowPrefetch in each iteration by 10. Compare the performance and choose the optimal prefetchSize for you.

Comment: @Grrrrr yes, my next step is to write the test program you are describing. The app server and the DB are on the same network segment.

Comment: Would you like to isolate the problem by running this program once on the same machine as the DB

Comment: @Grrrrr We've done that also. It's definitely the fetch size that affected it because we ran it several times back to back on the same box and saw these clear results.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your JVM memmory? HOw many columns are you fetching?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28161049/32453

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possible explanations:

1. Java is doing nothing, while Oracle is computing the **first 1000 rows** instead of first 10.
2. Oracle is doing nothing, while Java is computing the **last 1000 rows** instead of last 10.
3. Communication protocols (e.g. TCP/IP) wait a lot and then must handle more data at once, but the **peak data transfer will be throttled down by hardware limits**. This is countered by protocol's overhead, so there should be optimal fetch size and anything less or more would be slower ;))
4. It would get worse if the process of fetching is synchronous with other Java code, so that **Java asks for more rows only after processing the previous data** and Oracle does nothing in the mean time.

   > Imagine there are 3 people:
   >
   > - 1st one folds A4 paper in half
   > - 2nd one brings stacks of folded paper from one room to another
   > - 3rd cuts some shape from the folded paper.
   >
   > How big should the stacks be, if the 1st one has to wait until the 2nd one returns and the 2nd one has to wait until the 3rd one finishes their job?
   >
   > Stacks of 1000 will not be better than stacks of 10 i guess ;))

Comment: Finally! This is by far the clearest explanation. Your analogy makes a ton of sense. Thank you.

Comment: oh,, thanks for the award ;)) just a side note, i guess Oracle might precache the data that will be fetched next, so d) is not really an issue

Comment: So what will be this typical throttle size, aka practical size of pipe?

Comment: @Sumedh too many variables, you need to do your own tuning for your project, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_tuning

Comment: Given that in most case, processing of results and fetching are synchronous, I am curious to know, between each fetching, is Oracle doing any work to prepare for subsequent fetches?  If not, then it is simply like, 1st person only folds required number of papers that 3rd person ask for, and when 3rd person is cutting shape, 1st person just stand still without doing anything.  Then apart from point 3 about TCP/IP throttling, setting a fetch size of 1000 is not going to be worse than 10.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AdrianShum I guess so, but that would not be my assumption that Oracle is not pre-fetching. There might be a different setting for how many rows are pre-fetched regardless of the last fetch size, in which case you would want to set the fetch size to the same number... I don't have any insight into the Oracle internals though.

Answer (score 12):

As with everything, there is no `FAST=TRUE` setting. While the JDBC default fetch size of 10 is not ideal for your situation, it is OK for a "typical" OLTP application, and really isn't *that* bad for your case either, it seems. Apparently a large fetch size is not ideal for your situation either. But again, it isn't *that* bad to do 1000 at a time.

The other factor which you haven't mentioned is how *WIDE* the rows are that are being pulled. Consider that the chunk of data you are pulling from the database server across the network to the app server is the `sum(WIDTH*ROWS)`. If your rows are 5000 bytes across, and you're pulling 1000 at a time, then each fetch is going to bring in 5 MB of data. In another case, perhaps your rows are "skinny" at only 100 bytes across. Then fetching 1000 of those is only shuttling 100K pieces around.

Because only YOU can know what the data will look like coming back, the recommendation is to set the fetch size system-wide for the "general" case, then adjust the oddball queries individually as needed.

In general, I too have found 100 to be a better setting for large data processes. That's not a *recommendation*, but relaying an observation.

Comment: I agree about fetch size ~= 100 for large data processes.

Comment: Remember to profile with different numbers--for us we got improvements all the way up to 3200-4000 so try it out!

Answer (score 7):

BTW, at least with Oracle you need to be careful with the fetch size because Oracle driver sets aside an array for **maximum possible size** taken by each row, not the actual data size. So if you have a fat table, you memory footprint can suffer.

Take a look here - 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/memory.pdf

In Oracle you can find out maximum possible space taken by a column in user_tab_columns metadata table (data_length). It can be used to determine fetch size.

In rough tests, I found that 4 * 1024 * 1024 / sum(data_length for all columns of your table) is a reasonable fetch size.

Comment: Thanks for this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/memory.pdf.It perfectly explains how jdbc memory & fetch size stuff works.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/28161049/32453 for a list of tips on how to not require so much RAM but still use prefetch

Comment: @techcraver your pdf link is wrong. Should be http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/memory.pdf. Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

[The correct method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#i1023619) is to use setFetchSize.

> By default, when Oracle JDBC runs a query, it retrieves a result set
>   of 10 rows at a time from the database cursor. This is the default
>   Oracle row fetch size value. You can change the number of rows
>   retrieved with each trip to the database cursor by changing the row
>   fetch size value.
>
> Standard JDBC also enables you to specify the number of rows fetched
>   with each database round-trip for a query, and this number is referred
>   to as the fetch size. In Oracle JDBC, the row-prefetch value is used
>   as the default fetch size in a statement object. Setting the fetch
>   size overrides the row-prefetch setting and affects subsequent queries
>   run through that statement object.
>
> Fetch size is also used in a result set. When the statement object run
>   a query, the fetch size of the statement object is passed to the
>   result set object produced by the query. However, you can also set the
>   fetch size in the result set object to override the statement fetch
>   size that was passed to it.

Comment: For an individual query that makes sense, but setting the system property should just override the default, no?

Comment: You can set a system property, or configure it per connection: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/oraperf2.htm#1002425

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much what Adam H. said - there are no universal settings for every type of scenarios. It takes time for Oracle to fetch rows so time it spent waiting for rows on server side, before sending it to the client, could have been spent in your app should prefetch threshold be set lower, so performance suffers.

From what I recall Oracle also uses client side caching to provide scrollable cursors. It could help to set cursor to forward only, at least from memory prospective. At least  it used to be helpful in older versions of JDBC driver, perhaps the behavior changed since.

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 1):

daveslab, some more information...

If your application need the entire resultset to start processing the data, a larger fetch size can bring improvements. However, there is no magic number, is necessary to test the most beneficial value.

Setting the prefetch sized can Affect the performance of an application. Increasing the prefetch size will reduce the number of round-trips required to get all the data, but will Increase memory usage. This will depend on the number and size of the columns in the query and the number of rows expected to be returned. Also it will depend on the memory and CPU loading of the JDBC client machine. The optimum is a standalone client application will be different from the heavily loaded application server. The speed and latency of the network connection Should Also be considered.

Oracle JDBC client seems to pre-initialise some memory structures to hold the full prefetch size . So, if you set it prefetch size of 500, the 50x you allocate much memory than if you had prefetch size = 10. This is a huge extra demand on GC Especially if you are not actually reading Those rows. To think, you might be running the GC 50x Often more than needed if you Normally only fetch a few rows; this will be a big impact on your application responsiveness .

If possible, I recommend using the setFetchSize on a per-query basis. For example, if you know a particular query will only ever return a few rows, then set the fetch size to say 5. If you know a query will return 1000 rows, use a fetch size of 100.

As a heuristic, there are limited benefits from going over 50-100.

I hope you understand, I'm using google translator.