# Improving tOracleInput fetch size in Talend Open Studio

Tags: talend

I am trying to fetch around 100000 records from an oracle db server. As fetch size of ojdbc driver by default is 10 it takes too much time to process these records. I tried to alter `setFetchSize` api of `ResultSet` but Talend Open Studio isn't supporting this change of code. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried to use additional params in "advanced settings" tab of the tOracleInput component ?

Comment: no. How to do it? What parameter i need to include there?

Comment: there is a good discussion on fetch size here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220171/setting-oracle-size-of-row-fetches-higher-makes-my-app-slower.  issue may also be related to network connection speed between Talend runtime and your DB server.  Are they in same physical location and on the same network segment?   physical location and

Comment: I am fetching same amount of data from different source that is of ms sql server but the fetch rate is too good. But when retrieving data from oracle db server fetch rate is low. I have checked the thread mentioned above but not convincing for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In the advanced settings of the input components there is a use cursor / cursor size option. The name is very misleading but it does what you are looking for: set the fetchsize. I usually go with 100.